# validate display none in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

template is

```
<button type="submit" id="add" class="button_style" onclick="addreporter();" value="Add New Authorised Reporter">Add New Authorised Reporter</button>
<div id="authorisedreporter" style="display:none">
  <form method="post" action="{% url incident.views.about_me %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px;">First name:</td>
            <td>{{registerform.first_name}}{{registerform.first_name.errors}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td>
            <td>{{registerform.last_name}}{{registerform.last_name.errors}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Daytime phone:</td>
            <td>{{createprofile.phone_daytime}}{{createprofile.phone_daytime.errors}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile phone:</td>
            <td>{{createprofile.phone_mobile}}{{createprofile.phone_mobile.errors}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>{{registerform.email}}{{registerform.email.errors}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User name</td>
            <td>{{registerform.username}}{{registerform.username.errors}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>{{registerform.password}}{{registerform.password.errors}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 "">
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_qualified_firstaiders" style="margin: 0;vertical-align:middle" />Qualified First Aiders</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     </form>
    </div>
```

js:

```
function addreporter(){
        $("#authorisedreporter").toggle();
        if ($("#authorisedreporter").is(":visible")) {   
            $("#authorisedreporter").show();          
            $("#add").hide();
        }
    }
```

Using the jquery toggle,the  gets open  on click of this  `<button>Add new Authorized Reporter</button>`,every thing is fine except that if their is any error in form,the form is going to be in hide mode,if i want to see the errors again i need to click the  `<button>Add new Authorized Reporter</button>`,its a small logic to set if errors are in form,the form should not hide.What i thought is if i validate the `display:none` in `<div`> will work but no idea how to validate it in template.

Thanks

Comment: please close the `form`

Comment: No - form has to be above the `</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
<div id="authorisedreporter" {% if not registerform.errors %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>
```

Also, you might have to  modify `addreporter()` accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the add new authorised button while their is some error in form

Comment: Yes.. You can use the same logic. - `{% if not registerform.errors %}<button type="submit" id="add" class="button_style" onclick="addreporter();" value="Add New Authorised Reporter">Add New Authorised Reporter</button>{% endif %}`